# Embedding Wordpress blog in div?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have an existing single website (index.html) that works with a jquery content slider and I want to add my wordpress blog in one of the tabs. The blog is installed in mysite.com/blog/.
I saw a tutorial on how to show posts with php, but then when clicking those, it sends people off my page to the blog.
If I use iframe then I have SEO problems (or do I?) and the blog seems to be moving up when entering a comment on a post.

I hope somebody can help! 
Sincerely, Brian

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like [this](http://papermashup.com/creating-an-iframe-with-javascript/) 
Demo is [here](http://papermashup.com/demos/javascript-iframe.php)

Comment: What is the difference with "normal" iframes?
In this demo, when I click on "sign in", the myspace site is cut off and I cannot use it. Same with my site when someone tries to comment in the blog inside the iframe: the top of the site is cut off